# Why doesnt this insert statement work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this insert statement in mysql ( phpmyadmin to be exact but I think its a mysql syntax error )

```
    INSERT INTO rented_video 
    VALUES(NULL, 1, 2), 
    VALUES(NULL, 2, 1), 
    VALUES(NULL, 2, 2), 
    VALUES(NULL, 2, 3), 
    VALUES(NULL, 3, 4), 
    VALUES(NULL, 3, 5), 
    VALUES(NULL, 4, 6), 
    VALUES(NULL, 4, 7), 
    VALUES(NULL, 4, 8), 
    VALUES(NULL, 5, 9);
```

The Error is :

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'VALUES(NULL, 2, 1), VALUES(NULL, 2, 2), VALUES(NULL, 2, 3),
>   VALUES(NULL, 3' at line 3

Comment: what type are your columns? and do you allow NULL values for first column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should only one keyword `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO rented_video 
VALUES (NULL, 1, 2), 
       (NULL, 2, 1), 
       (NULL, 2, 2), 
       (NULL, 2, 3), 
       (NULL, 3, 4), 
       (NULL, 3, 5), 
       (NULL, 4, 6), 
       (NULL, 4, 7), 
       (NULL, 4, 8), 
       (NULL, 5, 9);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a21b/1)

Comment: @user1681542 now mark the answer as the good one to give the man some credit :)